# Can not successfully stop X server

Tags: command-line, nvidia, cuda, xserver

I am trying to install CUDA on my new Ubuntu install, but can't seem to get my X Server to shut off. I have tried:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

But after trying it in both the Ctrl + alt + f1 console and terminal, I am always sent to a black screen from which I can not interact with my environment, requiring a restart.

Edit: After the screen goes black, pressing ctrl + alt + f1-7 has no effect.

Comment: Once you see the black screen did you try switching to tty1 again?

Comment: Yeah @Ziazis, but none of the interfaces load.

Comment: Another method would be just ssh on that host once you stopped the lightdm. That should still work and you can finish your work on it without the need for a display on the host itself.

Comment: @Ziazis Clever! Inconvenient, but clever. I did that, and it worked out fine. Thanks!